# How do I use flow type to constrain the return value of this function?

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I want to say "`mySelector` returns a string". Can I do this with Flowtype?

```
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';

const mySelector = createSelector([anotherSelector], () => 'foo');
```

Comment: It is inferred automatically once you defined that the "result function" (`() => 'foo'`) returns `string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not already done so, it might be helpful to get type definitions for reselect into your project. You can fetch type definitions for your npm depenencies automatically using [flow-typed](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/README.md). (Reselect does ship with Typescript type definitions, and Flow may be able to read Typescript definitions in the future; but AFAIK Flow cannot read Typescript definitions at this time.)

Whether or not Flow correctly infers the type for `mySelector`, it may be useful to explicitly state the type that you expect. You can do that by putting a type annotation on `const` declaration:

```js
const mySelector: () => string = createSelector([anotherSelector], () => 'foo');
```

Explicit annotations like that can help to make sure that you are on the same page with the type checker. Flow will enforce the signature that you specify when you reference `mySelector`, unless Flow infers a contradictory type for `mySelector` in which case it will report an error.